# Excel VBA to Change Color Based on Theme Colors

Tags: vba, excel

I have the below code which works perfectly. However I want to change some of the typical color numbers to their theme colors and it isn't cooperating with me.

Tab 1:
.ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent3
.TintAndShade = -0.249977111117893

Tab 2: 192

Tab 3:
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight2
        .TintAndShade = -0.249977111117893

and so on, but I cant seem to find the correct way to format it in the array. Any help would be great ty!

```
Sub Change_Tab_Colors_Based_On_Array()
'
' Change_Tab_Colors_Based_On_Array Macro
'
' Declaration
    Dim iCntr, sht, arrColors, numColors
' Define the Array of Colors for Tabs - Repeats
    arrColors = Array(10, 9, 23, 46, 44, 50, 48)
    iCntr = 0
    numColors = UBound(arrColors) + 1
' Loop Through All Sheets in Workbook
    For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        sht.Tab.ColorIndex = arrColors((iCntr Mod 7))
        iCntr = iCntr + 1
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: your code runs for me, what is not working for you ? are you getting an error messgae ?

Comment: The current code runs, but I want to replace the 10 with .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent3 .TintAndShade = -0.249977111117893 and when i do it errors at "Invalid or unqualified reference"

Comment: anyone have any ideas? ty!